# Batch script stops working after reboot

Tags: windows, batch-file, mediainfo

so I have written a batch that worked as I intended to.
After I rebooted my windows however, I ran the batch again, and for some reason it wouldn't work anymore.

After breaking it down, eliminating/simplifying some code I found out that the problem has something to do with the MediaInfo CLI.
Here's the full code of the batch:

```
@echo off
set MEDIAINFO=C:\Progra~1\MediaInfo\MediaInfo.exe
set TEMPLATE=H:\test\Audio.txt

%MEDIAINFO% --Inform=file://%TEMPLATE% test.dts >H:\test\test.txt
pause
```

The template (Audio.txt) just contains:

```
Audio;%BitRate/String%
```

So as you can see, I broke it down to be super basic; and it even worked again after some time - without changing anything -, but after I rebooted again, it didn't work..
So, I know this sounds odd, but something must have triggered it to work again. I have no clue what that might have been though.

I'm pretty confused as to why this is happening, so any help would be much appreciated.
PS: Sorry if my grammar might not be correct, but English is not my native language.

Comment: What was the failure behavior?  Were there any specific error messages?

Comment: What appears when you remove the `@echo off` line?

Comment: When the machine restarts, are you sure that the H: drive letter is mapped. Before running the script, use `NET USE` to see if it is connected.

Comment: @DavidRuhmann: No error messages. Just an empty output file is created (test.txt)

Comment: @Paul : When I remove the `@echo off` line, everything is printed with paths just as normal. And yes, H: is mapped. Also tried it on different drives. Last time I rebooted the computer was ~30 minutes ago, still not working, so whatever is triggering it to work, I did not trigger it yet.

Comment: Have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa767731(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, that maybe you should change `--Inform=file://%TEMPLATE%` to `--Inform="file:///%TEMPLATE:\=/%"`.  Also, just for the sake of convention, `set "MEDIAINFO=%PROGRAMFILES%\MediaInfo\MediaInfo.exe"` with the "var=value" pair quoted, and call it like `"%MEDIAINFO%" --Inform...` (or is MediaInfo in `%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%`?)